# How to place a small image as a watermark on the desktop in KDE?

Tags: desktop-background, plasma, extension

In Cinnamon, it is possible to add an image as a watermark, with [this](https://github.com/germanfr/watermark-cinnamon) extension.

[image]

This is a screenshot of my computer (Linux Mint 19) from April 2019. The cat is added as a watermark.

When an image is placed as a watermark, it remains there even when the wallpaper is changed. Also, the size and the transparency of the image can be modified.

Is something similar available on KDE Plasma? I am using Kubuntu 22.04.

I am looking for a plasma widget which can do this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Media Frame` widget and choose your picture there.

Afterwards, open `Edit Mode`, and click on `Hide Background` to hide the black background for transparent images.

[image]